# How to continue infinite while loop even after exception

Tags: java, loops, exception, while-loop, tcp

I have written a piece of code to send data over TCP to a server, but the server may not always be up. So I thought I could have the sender try transmission of data in 10 second intervals in an infinite while loop. But the problem is when the server is not up, exceptions occur in the sender, which are expected. I tried to handle the exceptions with try and catch so that the loop can continue even if they occur but I couldn't and after the exceptions occur while loop breaks and nothing happens in the next time interval.

How can  I write the program in such way (which can continue the loop even if exceptions occur) ?

PS. the program is initialed by calling the loop and sending two values to it.

```
public void loop(String serverIP, String GSID)  {

    while (true) {

        try {
            dataTransmission(serverIP, GSID);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

public void dataTransmission(String GSID,String serverIP ) {


    System.out.println("GS ID=" + GSID);
    System.out.println("server IP=" + serverIP);


    Socket s1 = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedReader is = null;
    PrintWriter pwr = null;
    String response = null;


    String ServerIP = "localhost";


    try {
        s1 = new Socket(ServerIP, 4445);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s1.getInputStream()));
        pwr = new PrintWriter(s1.getOutputStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }



    // send GSID to Server
    pwr.println(GSID);
    pwr.flush();


    // get GS IP
    String GSIP = null;
    try {
        GetGasStationIP gsip = new GetGasStationIP();
        GSIP = gsip.getSourceIP();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }


    // send GSIP to Server
    pwr.println(GSIP);
    pwr.flush();
    //response = is.readLine();
    //System.out.println("Server Response : " + response);


    // send time
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    pwr.println(dtf.format(now));
    pwr.flush();
    //response = is.readLine();
    //System.out.println("Server Response : " + response);


    try {
        is.close();
        pwr.close();
        br.close();
        s1.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Connection Closed");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know if I understand your Question right, but why not using in catch block "continue"?

Comment: I guess some other exception is occuring other than `InterruptedException`. You can try catching all `Exception` instead of just `InterruptedException` in your `loop` method. This might help you.

Comment: @Nils `continue` wouldn't do anything here? There's no code after the catch so it would continue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is most likely throwing a runtime exception that you are not handling.

try catching `Exception` instead of `InterruptedException` in the while loop (albeit not recommended).

You need to catch the exact runtime exception that happens when the server is down and handle it.